# How to run VLC player in root

Tags: root, vlc

I have installed a vlc in centos 6.5. I want to run it as root. But I get the following error,

> "VLC is not supposed to be run as root. Sorry. If you need to use
>   real-time priorities and/or privileged TCP ports you can use
>   vlc-wrapper (make sure it is Set-UID root and cannot be run by
>   non-trusted users first)."

Answer (score 74):

This is what worked for me. No compilation required.

```
sed -i 's/geteuid/getppid/' /usr/bin/vlc
```

Using VLC media player **2.0.3** Twoflower on a Raspberry Pi.

**Explanation:**
The initialization script check if the UID is equals to zero. Zero is reserved for the root user. Using `sed` to replace `geteuid` for `getppid` fools the initialization script because it is always `> 0`.

While running the VLC as root is not recommended, it works. Be aware of the risks and obviously do not do it for production environments.

For Freebsd and other finicky unices and macos use the proper full syntax:

```
sed -i '' 's/geteuid/getppid/' /usr/local/bin/vlc
```

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation part. A lot of people skip that, and then its just magical one liner that fixes a problem. Rather then chance to learn.

Answer (score 20):

One way around this is recompiling. Pass the `--enable-run-as-root` flag to `./configure` and vlc should be able to run as root. The above answer is from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/run-vlc-using-root-account-703319/).

Comment: recompiling is not the only way, just change the call to geteuid to deliver 1. I describe this at http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Run_vlc_as_root

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk, thanks for providing me the information.

Comment: Could you please mark the question as answered?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk : dead link...

Comment: @Alexandre Bourlier: works (again)

Answer (score 6):

See [Run vlc as root - LinuxIntro](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Run_vlc_as_root):

- backup the VLC binary:

  ```
   # cp /usr/bin/vlc /usr/bin/vlc-backup
  ```
- find the call to `geteuid` inside the VLC binary:

  ```
   # needle=$(objdump -d /usr/bin/vlc | grep euid | tail -1 | awk '{print "\\x"$2"\\x"$3"\\x"$4"\\x"$5"\\x"$6;}')
  ```
- replace the call to just deliver `01`:

  ```
   # sed -ir "s/$needle/\xb8\x01\x00\x00\x00/" /usr/bin/vlc
  ```
- test it

VLC should now run under the root user!

Comment: That is extremely beautiful. Works like a charm and I am amazed at the cleverness to think this up.

Comment: wow, just read this, you made my day!!!

Answer (score 2):

Kevin in comments of the question suggested using vlc-wrapper. I had troubles finding out how to use it so I'll describe how I made it work:

you need to set your non-privileged user in SUDO_UID:
export SUDO_UID=1000

if you don't have a user to run vlc under create one:

```
useradd -g users vlc
# this will show you the uid of vlc user
id -u vlc
```

if you want SUDO_UID variable permanent, add it to bashrc:

```
echo "export SUDO_UID=1000" >> /root/.bashrc
```

be careful not to write single > instead of >>

then use vlc-wrapper instead of vlc

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to run VLC as root by modifying the VLC binary, located in `/usr/bin`

First, you'll need a hex-editor, like Bless:

```
sudo apt-get install bless
```

Then, you'll open the VLC binary with the hex-editor:

```
sudo bless /usr/bin/vlc
```

Search and change the `geteuid` string by `getppid`, save and exit.

You can now launch VLC as root.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `main menu` find `vlc` and set property as:

```
gksu -u vlc
```

or simply in terminal type

```
gksu -u <username(no root)> vlc
```

For example, if you have `abc` user your command will be:

```
gksu -u abc vlc
```